# Weird result when converting string to float

Tags: php, floating-point

I want to convert a string to float but I've some problem.
Here is my code

```
    $dataValue = $item[$data];
    $dataValue = trim($dataValue);
    var_dump($dataValue);echo "<br>";
    $dataValue = str_replace(',', '.', $dataValue);
    var_dump($dataValue);echo "<br>";
    var_dump(floatval($dataValue));echo "<br>";
    var_dump(floatval('4.02'));echo "<br>";
```

And the results

```
string(7) "4,02"
string(7) "4.02"
float(4)
float(4.02)
```

I don't understand the third result, why I have 4 and not 4.02 ?

Thanks

EDIT:

My new code :

```
$dataValue = $item[$data];

        echo mb_detect_encoding($dataValue) . "<br>";

        $dataValue = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $dataValue);
        $dataValue = trim($dataValue);
        $dataValue = str_replace(',', '.', $dataValue);

        echo mb_detect_encoding($dataValue) . "<br>";

        var_dump($dataValue);echo"<br >";
        $dataValue = mb_convert_encoding($dataValue, "UTF-8");
        var_dump($dataValue);echo"<br >";
        $dataValue = str_replace(',', '.', $dataValue);
        $dataValue = floatval($dataValue);
        var_dump($dataValue);echo"<br >";`
```

And the result

```
ASCII
ASCII
string(7) "4.02"
string(7) "4.02"
float(4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only 4 visible characters, yet `var_dump()` claims that there are 7. I surmise that there is an invisible character before the decimal point that is causing `floatval()` to terminate conversion prematurely. You can verify this by looking at a hex dump of the contents of `$dataValue`.

**EDIT:**

It appears that your string is encoded in UTF-16LE. Use mb or iconv to convert it to ASCII/UTF-8 before processing.

Comment: yes I think it's the problem. `echo bin2hex($dataValue);` give me `34002c00300032`

Comment: `unpack()` will let you get at it.

Comment: And `print_r(unpack('H*', $dataValue));` give me `Array ( [1] => 34002c00300032 ) `

Comment: First, stop trimming it. Then, convert it **from UTF-16LE**.

Comment: Now i have `string(5) "4.02"` and after floatval() I have `float(0)`

Comment: I put a trim() after converting, and now it's ok. Thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tested this:

```
$dataValue = "4,02";
$dataValue = trim($dataValue);
var_dump($dataValue);echo "<br>";
$dataValue = str_replace(',', '.', $dataValue);
var_dump($dataValue);echo "<br>";
var_dump(floatval($dataValue));echo "<br>";
var_dump(floatval('4.02'));echo "<br>";
```

Output:

```
string(4) "4,02"
string(4) "4.02"
float(4.02)
float(4.02)
```

Are you sure that the posted code produces the described problem?

EDIT

Try add this this:

```
$dataValue = preg_replace("/[^0-9\,]/", '', $dataValue);
```

Comment: This helps test my theory - in this case, the previously double-quoted string is now in single-quotes.

Comment: @SouthpawHare Perhaps! Really possible.

Comment: With your code it's work. But my value provide from an array `$item[$data]` what's weird to is the size of 7 char whereas there is only 4 char visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use number_format(float_number, decimal_places):

```
var_dump(number_format(floatval($dataValue) ,2));
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the difference lies in the fast that $dataValue is a double-quoted string in the third output, while you use a single-quoted string in the fourth example.  In PHP, [these work differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php) when dealing with how they are treated as literals.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume it has to do with accuracy issues in PHP's float implementation.

Check out this: [Wikipedia: Floating Point Accuracy Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)